# Analytic proof of equation of circle passing through intersection of two other circles - From Schaum's Guide

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

I'm trying to teach myself calculus and *very* slowly working through Schaum's guide. This question is asked elsewhere but I'm afraid I need the answer broken down more:

Let $ \mathscr{C_{1}} $ and $ \mathscr C_{2} $ be two intersecting circles determined by the equations $$ x^2 + y^2 + A_{1}x + B_{1}y + C_{1} = 0 $$ and $$ x^2 + y^2 + A_{2}x + B_{2}y + C_{2} = 0. $$ For any number $ k≠−1 $, show that $$ x^2 + y^2 + A_{1}x + B_{1}y + C_{1} + k ( x^2 + y^2 + A_{2}x + B_{2}y + C_{2} ) = 0 $$ is the equation of a circle through the intersection points of $\mathscr{C_{1}}$ and $\mathscr C_{2}$. Show, conversely, that every such circle may be represented by such an equation for a suitable $ k $.


If anyone could give a pretty detailed walk-through on this I would be supremely grateful. I'm supposed to be able to answer/show it using only analytic geometry (no trig or calculus).

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: The second statement you should prove is false: circle $\mathscr C_{2}$ cannot be represented by the given equation for some value of $k$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first point, note that if $M_1(x_1,y_1)$ is one of those two points of intersection, then $x_1^2+y_1^2+A_1x_1+B_1y_1+C_1=0$ because $M_1$ is on the first. Likewise $x_1^2+y_1^2+A_2x_1+B_2y_1+C_2=0$ because it's on the other circle.

So for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that at least one of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is nonzero:

$$\alpha(x_1^2+y_1^2+A_1x_1+B_1y_1+C_1)+\beta(x_1^2+y_1^2+A_2x_1+B_2y_1+C_2)=\alpha\cdot0+\beta\cdot0=0$$

Now let the coordinates vary: $\alpha(x^2+y^2+A_1x+B_1y+C_1)+\beta(x^2+y^2+A_2x+B_2y+C_2)=0$ is the equation of a circle which also contains $M_1$. *(divide by $\alpha+\beta$ to get the equation as $x^2+y^2+Ux+Vy+W=0$, which is the equation of a circle.)*

Note that if $\alpha=\beta=0$, this is not anymore the equation of a circle, as it simplifies to $0=0$.

---

Conversely, if you have a circle $\mathscr C$ through these two points of intersection (call them $M_1,M_2$), then pick a third point on the circle, $M_3(x_3,y_3)$, and choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that at least one of $\alpha,\beta$ is nonzero and

$$\alpha(x_3^2+y_3^2+A_1x_3+B_1y_3+C_1)+\beta(x_3^2+y_3^2+A_2x_3+B_2y_3+C_2)=0$$

Then, letting $x$ and $y$ vary, $\alpha(x^2+y^2+A_1x+B_1y+C_1)+\beta(x^2+y^2+A_2x+B_2y+C_2)=0$ is the equation of a circle which goes through the three points $M_1,M_2$ and $M_3$. There is only one such circle, and it's $\mathscr C$. If $\alpha\ne0$, divide by $\alpha$ to get the equation as in your question.

Like in the first part, if $\alpha=\beta=0$, you don't get the equation of a circle, so the additional condition on $\alpha,\beta$ is again necessary.

---

Note, as pointed out in the comment above, that it's always possible to find such $\alpha,\beta$, but in the form in your question it's not always possible to find such a $k$: for $\mathscr C=\mathscr C_2$ we would need $\alpha=0$ and $\beta\ne1$, which would lead to $k=\infty$).

Comment: Thank you Jean-Claude. I've been thinking over your answer and following the edits which I think I can partially follow.

My intuitive reasoning through it follows you for the first point, that if M1 is point (x,y) then adding both equations with constants a and b (for any two constants where at least one constant is not zero) will contain point M1 and will be a circle.

I'm struggling to see how the other point (M2) would also be on the new circle though.

Thank you again, I've literally been losing sleep over this question.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions for a quadratic equation to represent a circle are:

- the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ are equal and nonzero,
- the coefficient of $xy$ is zero.

You easily check that these hold for the three given equations (with a small exception).

Next, you can check that the two intersection points are common to all these circles.

Comment: Thank you Yves - the first three points make sense, how does one check that the intersection points are common to all three circles, e.g. for two generic intersection points M1 and M2 where M1 is point (a,b) and M2 is point (u,v)?

Comment: @AKJ: what can you say about an intersection point ?

Comment: It's shared by two equations???

Comment: @AKJ: yes, and then what about the third ?

Comment: Right, the two intersection points are shared by all three circle equations. I think I need another hint.

Comment: @AKJ: what for ???